# Shopify Debut Theme - Show max variant price on featured collection homepage

Tags: shopify, liquid

By default, the Debut theme shows the lowest variant price. I would like to show the max variant price on the collection featured products on the homepage and collection pages. I was able to change this on the individual product page by editing the product-price.liquid code but haven't had any luck changing it on the collection grid. The URL is https://anaholagranola.com/

I changed a line of code to this but it only changed the product page

```
{%- assign price = product.price_max -%}
```

Comment: What does the code for the product thumbnail look like in your theme?  There's probably somewhere that references either `product.price` or `product.price_min` that you can change to `product.price_max`

Comment: @DaveB Here is the whole product-price.liquid code, everything that I've read says that this snippet controls product price sitewide but I can't seem to get it to change anywhere other than the individual product page.

https://www.codepile.net/raw/aVPo786X.liq

Comment: @DaveB here is the featured-product.liquid code https://www.codepile.net/raw/r0emlM0N.js

Comment: Hmm. Oddly, that first snippet seems to only reference `variant.price`, not any of the price fields on the `product` object.

Comment: Yes, that is what I changed to 

{%- assign price = product.price_max -%}

Comment: Aye, I saw that - but because the price rendering snippet as-written is only referring to the `variant.price` the only thing that matters is which variant is being passed in.  In the featured-product snippet, that variant is named `current_variant` and is being assigned thusly: `{%- assign current_variant = product.selected_or_first_available_variant -%}`

Comment: Is there a way to change that to just pull the max variant price?

Comment: Each variant only has a single price - the min/max price on a product comes from the range of prices amongst the variants.  I myself would probably make a new file in the `snippets` folder, start with the code in that `product-price` file and change it to take in a `product` object instead of a `variant` object

Comment: hmm sounds a bit above my coding skillset

Answer (score 0):

The theme seems to be displaying prices based off of a single variant being passed into the theme's `product-price` snippet. It's going to take a little bit more coding to update things to show the product's max price.

Here are two ideas for how you might do this:

1. Select the highest-priced variant from the variant list and use that as the `current_variant` in your `featured-product` code.

This might look something as follows:

Find:

```
 {%- assign current_variant = product.selected_or_first_available_variant -%}
```

Replace with:
{%- assign sorted_variant_list = product.variants | sort: 'price' | reverse -%}
{%- assign current_variant = sorted_variant_list.first -%}

This code will sort the variants by price (ascending by default) then reverses the order (so they should now be in descending price order) and then selects the first variant from that list, which should give you the highest-priced variant that will be fed into the `product-price` snippet.

2. Write a better price display snippet that takes a product, not a variant

Create a new file in your theme's `snippets` folder and give it a catchy name.

Using the existing `product-price` file as a template, we might get something like this:

```
{%- assign money_price = price | money -%}

<dl class="price{% if available and compare_at_price > price %} price--on-sale{% endif %}" data-price>

  {% if section.settings.show_vendor %}
    <div class="price__vendor">
      <dt>
        <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'products.product.vendor' | t }}</span>
      </dt>
      <dd>
        {{ product.vendor }}
      </dd>
    </div>
  {% endif %}

  <div class="price__regular">
    <dt>
      <span class="visually-hidden visually-hidden--inline">{{ 'products.product.regular_price' | t }}</span>
    </dt>
    <dd>
      {% if available %}
        {% if compare_at_price > price %}
          <s class="price-item price-item--regular" data-regular-price>
            {{ compare_at_price | money }}
          </s>
        {% else %}
          <span class="price-item price-item--regular" data-regular-price>
            {{ money_price }}
          </span>
        {% endif %}
      {% else %}
        <span class="price-item price-item--regular" data-regular-price>
          {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
        </span>
      {% endif %}
    </dd>
  </div>
  <div class="price__sale">
    <dt>
      <span class="visually-hidden visually-hidden--inline">{{ 'products.product.sale_price' | t }}</span>
    </dt>
    <dd>
      <span class="price-item price-item--sale" data-sale-price>
        {{ money_price }}
      </span>
      <span class="price-item__label" aria-hidden="true">{{ 'products.product.on_sale' | t }}</span>
    </dd>
  </div>
  <div class="price__unit">
    <dt>
      <span class="visually-hidden visually-hidden--inline">{{ 'products.product.unit_price_label' | t }}</span>
    </dt>
  </div>
</dl>
```

I created the above by simply removing the `variant` pieces from the pricing snippet.  To use this revised snippet you will need to pass in `price`, `compare_at_price` and `available` values.  (Change 'product-price-revised' to whatever you called the snippet file that you created)

```
{% include 'product-price-revised', price: product.price_max, compare_at_price: product.compare_at_price_max, available: product.available %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Debut Theme Snippets -> `product-card-grid.liquid`

Replace:

`{% include 'product-price', variant: product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}`

With:

`{% include 'product-price', variant: product %}`

Then in the Snippet -> `product-price.liquid`

Replace:

`{%- assign price = variant.price -%}`

With:

`{%- assign price = variant.price_max -%}`

I tested it on the Debut theme its working. You may also try this.